# How do I use the VS Code keyboard shortcuts for changing a notebook cell to code or markdown?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vscode-keybinding

It used to be that you could switch a cell between markdown and code in VS Code's version of Jupyter notebook. You can't now I looked at the keyboard shortcuts and it won't even accept the ESCAPE key before using y for code or m for markdown.

Is there a work around?

Answer (score 1):

Related change history: [Disable single key keybinding when focus in output #175710](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/175710).

The code where the keyboard shortcut is defined is https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/contrib/notebook/browser/contrib/cellCommands/cellCommands.ts.

The current definition of the keyboard shortcut at the time of this writing for Windows and Linux users:

> ```json
> { "key": "y", "command": "notebook.cell.changeToCode",
>                 "when": "notebookEditorFocused && !inputFocus && !notebookOutputFocused && activeEditor == 'workbench.editor.notebook' && notebookCellType == 'markup'" },
> { "key": "m", "command": "notebook.cell.changeToMarkdown",
>                 "when": "notebookEditorFocused && !inputFocus && !notebookOutputFocused && activeEditor == 'workbench.editor.notebook' && notebookCellType == 'code'" },
> ```

For example, if you're trying to use those keyboard shortcuts while the input or output part of the cell is focused, then the when clause will not be matched.

If you want the when clause to be different, then just copy and paste what you find in the defaultKeybindings.json pseudo file into your keybindings.json file, and then edit the when clause to be whatever you want it to be.

Comment: This works well. Can similar keybindings be defined for switching to other languages? For example, changing the language to 'raw' or 'shellscript'?

Comment: @Sang whether it's a code cell or a markdown isn't really that much about language as you think it is. You want the command `Notebook: Change Cell Language`.

Answer (score 1):

try uninstalling any jupyter extensions you have installed in vs code, then reinstall them and Jupyter Keymap

I was struggling with vs code not having the same keyboard shortcuts as jupyter in the browser for a long time. Finally figured it was the extensions I had installed.

Hope this helps.

p.s. setting custom keymaps in vscode is accessed via

```
cmd + k cmd + s
```